# TensorFlow: Will more memory be consumed if I handle secondary computations within a graph?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

If I have a trained Imagnet model from Google (inception-resnet-v2) and the model actually gives me two outputs back: the `logits`, and a list called end_points where I can extract the final predicted layer that has been performed with softmax activation, i.e. a variable called `predictions`. However, this does not definitively give me the class label which I would require for predictions. To do so, I would either have to do `label = tf.argmax(predictions, 1)` **after** I defined the train_op in the graph, so that I won't affect the original computation.

Alternatively, I can use `np.argmax(sess.run(predictions), 1)` which is computed out of the graph.

My question is if I choose to do the first approach, would it consume more memory and affect my computation (in terms of the batch_size I can use)? Is it safer and better to just compute the necessary labels out of the graph?

Comment: it doesn't matter in which order the graph is constructed, `session.run` doesn't know if you added `argmax` before train_op or after

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I think the question is a different one: Is numpy argmax more efficient than tensorflow argmax, when the input to both comes from tensorflow?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov yes but will the additional construction of a graph that is run only after the training has been done consume more memory? Meaning to say if I originally constructed the graph using my maximum memory in my current batch size, if I reconstruct the graph to compute additional operations to run within the same session (with my original training staying the same) will my training be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue multiple `.run` calls, the graph definition is cached. If you modify Graph, it'll need to re-encode it and send it again. So there may be a bit of extra memory used by `graph_def.SerializeToString` the first time you run modified graph, but it shouldn't affect `.run` steps after that.

Relevant logic is in [session.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b00fc538638f87ac45be9105057b9865f0f9418b/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L1037), note the line which checks `self._graph.version > self._current_version`

```
 def _extend_graph(self):
    # Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the runtime.
    with self._extend_lock:
      if self._graph.version > self._current_version:
        # pylint: disable=protected-access
        graph_def, self._current_version = self._graph._as_graph_def(
            from_version=self._current_version,
            add_shapes=self._add_shapes)
        # pylint: enable=protected-access

        with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
          tf_session.TF_ExtendGraph(
              self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
        self._opened = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I confirm with you that any operation that is additionally defined in the graph (and even if it is not run) will consume more memory? It seems like it should be quite flexible to use either `tf.argmax` or `np.argmax` - but for more complex operations, would you recommend that I do it within the graph or outside the graph in terms of memory considerations?

Comment: generally it's more efficient to do computations inside the graph, because moving data across TensorFlow<->Python incurs a memory copy

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight. This is something I've never really known!